# Is there a mission timer in StarCraft II?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

I'm working on some of the achievements in the single-player Wings Of Liberty campaign. Several of them are in the form of "Complete the mission in X minutes or less".

Is there any in-game way I can see how much time has elapsed since I started the mission, or will I have to keep track of the time on my own somehow?

Comment: A good question. I've tried to keep track of time on my own before and it appears as though game time is not always real time. It probably factors in the full time of skipped cutscenes, etc.

Comment: @JavadocMD If you are playing on fast or faster, then game minutes pass faster than real minutes. Fast is about 20% faster than real time, and faster is about 38% faster than real time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a built in timer since patch 1.1.

It's in the options gameplay -> display in game timer.

Answer (score 6):

You can save your mission and then view the elapsed time on the load saved mission screen, but that is the only way to view it in-game as far as I know. As for keeping track of your time on your own, keep in mind that game time and real time are different things, and the achievements are for game time.

- Normal speed is equal to real time.
- 1 real minute playing on fast is about 1.2 minutes of game time
- 1 real minute playing on faster is about 1.38 minutes of game time

Comment: What speed do the single-player missions run at? They're noticeably slower than ladder matches for sure, which I believe run at Faster speed. I'm going to guess Normal?

Comment: @Brant I believe normal is the default, but you can change it to whatever you'd like. In a mission go to Options -> Gameplay, you should see a game speed slider.

Comment: default Speed depends on difficulty chosen: Normal->normal speed, Hard->fast, Brutal->faster. You can always make it faster but never slower than default.

Comment: @F.S. Ah, I couldn't remember if I had manually set faster or if it was because I set my campaign difficulty to brutal. I never tried slowing it down, so I was not aware you couldn't set it below the default. Thanks for clarifying.