# Is there any possibility how to see the elapsed GAME time in multiplayer SC2?

Tags: starcraft-2

I know that this question has been discussed a bit in numerous topics about SC2, but still perhaps there is a possibility how to see the elapsed **game time** ingame? Or is it perhaps planned in future SC2 patches?

For campaign missions, you can save and reload the mission then read it on the loading screen. I'm mainly interested in this for multiplayer games, however.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6261/starcraft-2-mission-timer

Comment: @dbemerlin The question explicitly states the answer from that question and explains why that is not applicable. So I wouldn't call it a duplicate.

Comment: I can see how this would be useful for gauging when an attack might be coming, or how good our own build is going.  I guess an old fashioned alternative is to get a digital clock and stick it near your computer -it won't be "game" time, but you could still get a sense that a 2 gate will hit at 3minutes or whatever.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit: There is now an in game clock feature. It can be enabled by going to options, gameplay, and then enabling the in-game clock. The below is old information and no longer relevant.

There is currently no way to view the time elapsed in game. The lack of this has led to [numerous](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/374769452#1) [threads](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/375111133#1) [requesting](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/166496806#2) [the feature](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/375111340) on blizzard's forums. There appear to be no plans currently to add it, but I would not rule out the possibility of it being added eventually given all the requests blizzard is receiving.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I really hope there will be an option to view the time added in future patches. Marking this as an accepted question because this is the info i wanted.